# jython convert text file to list of strings

Tags: java, list, text, jython, data-conversion

I must convert a text file into a list of strings separated by commas (with no whitespace and no first line). After printing that, I need to print the name of each state, how many lines contain each state, The sum of all Cen2010 values (the 1st number in each line) for each state, sum of Est2013 values (the last number in each line) for each state, and the total change from Cen2010 population to Est2013 population for each state.

Text File Example:

> NAME,STNAME,Cen2010,Base2010,Est2010,Est2011,Est2012,Est2013
>   "Abingdon city",Illinois,3319,3286,3286,3270,3242,3227
>   "Addieville village",Illinois,252,252,252,250,250,247
>   "Addison village",Illinois,36942,36964,37007,37181,37267,37385
>   "Adeline village",Illinois,85,85,85,84,84,83

Current Code:

```
def readPopest():
  censusfile=pickAFile()
  cf=open(censusfile,"rt")
  cflines=cf.readlines()
  for i in range(len(cflines)-1):
    lines=cflines[i+1]
    estimate=lines.strip().split(',')
    print estimate
```

Returning:
['"Abingdon city"', 'Illinois', '3319', '3286', '3286', '3270', '3242', '3227']
['"Addieville village"', 'Illinois', '252', '252', '252', '250', '250', '247']
['"Addison village"', 'Illinois', '36942', '36964', '37007', '37181', '37267', '37385']
['"Adeline village"', 'Illinois', '85', '85', '85', '84', '84', '83']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can import this data to SQL database and then it is very easy to sum, filter etc.

But in Python we have dictionaries. You can read data and fill dictionary where key name is name of the state. Then for each line you add town to list of towns in this state, and add numbers to already saved numbers. Of course for 1st town in state you must create structure with two arrays. One for towns, and one for numbers. In code it looks like:

```
def add_items(main_dict, state, town, numbers):
    try:
        towns_arr, numbers_arr = main_dict[state]
        towns_arr.append(town)
        for i in range(len(numbers)):
            numbers_arr[i] += numbers[i]
    except KeyError:
        town_arr = [town, ]
        main_dict[state] = [town_arr, numbers]
```

Now you must use it in your main code that reads file:

```
    state_dict = {}
    cf = open(censusfile, "rt")
    lines = cf.readlines()
    for line in lines[1:]:  # we skip 1st line
        arr = line.strip().split(',')
        town = arr[0]
        state = arr[1]
        numbers = [int(x) for x in arr[2:]]
        add_items(state_dict, state, town, numbers)
    print(state_dict)
```

As a homework try to print this dictionary in desired format.